# Questions about memory alignement in structures and portability of the sizeof operator

Tags: c, memory-management, sizeof

I have a question about structure padding and memory alignment optimizations regarding structures in C language. I am sending a structure over the network, I know that, for run-time optimizations purposes, the memory inside a structure is not contiguous. I've run some tests on my local computer and indeed, sizeof(my_structure) was different than the sum of all my structure members. I ran some research to find out two things :

- First, the sizeof() operator retrieves the padded size of the structure (i.e the real size that would be stored in memory).
- When specifying **__*attribute*__**((**__*packed*__**)) in the declaration of the structure this optimization is disabled by the compiler, so sizeof(my_structure) will be exactly the same as the sum of the fields of my structure.

That being said, i am wondering if the `sizeof` operator was getting the padded size on every compilers implementation and on every architecture, in other words, is it always safe to copy a structure with `memcpy` for example using the `sizeof` operator such as :

```
memcpy(struct_dest, struct_src, sizeof(struct_src));
```

I am also wondering what is the real purpose of **__*attribute*__**((**__*packed*__**)), is it used to send a less important amount the data on a network when submitting a structure or is it, in fact, used to avoid some unspecified and platform-dependant `sizeof` operator behaviour ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: If `sizeof` was broken, we'd be screwed. Luckily, it isn't - at worst, some half-assed compiler written by an undergraduate over the course of five weeks fails to implement it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it always safe to copy a structure with memcpy for example using the sizeof operator**

Yes, it is and that is the purpose of providing the `sizeof` operator.

Usually `__attribute__((__packed__))` is used not for size considerations but when you want want to to make sure of the layout of a structure is exactly as you want it to be.

For ex: 
If a structure is to be used to match hardware or be sent on a wire then it needs to have the exact same layout without any padding.This is because different architectures usually implement different kinds & amounts of padding and alignment and the only way to ensure common ground is to remove padding out out of the picture by using packing.

Answer (score 2):

Different compilers on different architectures can and do use different padding. So for wire transmission it is not uncommon to pack structs to achieve a consistent binary layout. This can then cater for the code at each end of the wire running on different architecture.

However you also need to make sure that your data types are the same size if you use this approach. For example, on 64 bit systems, long is 4 bytes on Windows and 8 bytes almost everywhere else. And you also need to deal with endianness issues. The standard is to transmit over the wire in network byte order. In practice you would be better using a dedicated serialization library rather than trying to reinvent solutions to all these issues.

Comment: `s/Windows/64-bit Windows/` and `s/almost everywhere else/on most other 64-bit systems/`, but yeah.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer, I already took care of endianness issues :). I agree for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

> I am sending a structure over the network

Stop there.  Perhaps some would disagree with me on this (in practice you do see a lot of projects doing this), but  `struct` is a way of laying out things in memory - it's not a serialization mechanism.  By using this tool for the job, you're already tying yourself to a bunch of non-portable assumptions.

Sure, you may be able to fake it with things like structure padding pragmas and attributes, but - can you really?  Even with those non-portable mechanisms you never know what quirks might show up.  I recall working in a code base where "packed" structures were used, then suddenly taking it to a platform where access had to be word aligned...  even though it was nominally the same compiler (thus supported the same proprietary extensions) it produced binaries which crashed.  Any pain you get from this path is probably deserved, and I would say only take it if you can be 100% sure it will only run in a given compiler and environment, and that will never change.  I'd say the safer bet is to write a proper serialization mechanism that doesn't allow writing structures around across process boundaries.

Comment: Well, it isn't indeed a serialization mechanism, but I doesn't use it to this purpose, in fact I am using Raw sockets to send packets on a low level. Sending a structure over the wire is simply the commonest way to send raw data, and this is how all the protocols implemented in the OSI stack (below application data) are actually working. A structure is a common way to lay out things in memory as you said, but it is language dependant, in the reality a packed structure is only a set of bits.

Comment: It's true that, say, Linux kernel (to take an example) might use packed structures for this purpose, but they (a) are taking a dependency on specific compilers and architectures and (b) must take great care to do so correctly.  Does that make it a good idea?  I would still say that this qualifies as "using `struct`s as a serialization mechanism" and based on your response I would spend more time thinking about what that means.  :-)

Comment: You're right about the compiler issues I could face, although the project I'm developping is a university assignement and might not be compiled on other platforms. I like however your approach of how to deal with this. I thank you for your experience about that, I was wondering about the problems you were facing actually. I'm aware about what serialization mechanism are by the way thank you :)